# Is it possible to popup a sigin/up page(pivot) with appbar?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to popup a sigin/up page(pivot) with appbar ? And is it possible auto fill the screen(has SystemTray or not)?

Comment: If you want fullscreen and appbar, why don't you just navigate to a new page?

Comment: @KooKiz u should read this post: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/introducing-the-concept-of-places.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible

To open a popup in your Mainpage, using (example popup when page loaded):

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (obj, args) =>
            {
                Popup popup = new Popup()
                {
                    IsOpen = true
                };


                popup.Child = new PivotPage1(this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight, this, popup);
            };
    }
```

In your PivotPage, create addition constructor:

```
    private PhoneApplicationPage parent = null;
    private IApplicationBar parentAppBar = null;
    private Popup popup = null;

    public PivotPage1(double w, double h, PhoneApplicationPage p, Popup pop) : this()
    {
        Width = w;
        Height = h;
        parent = p;
        popup = pop;

        Loaded += (obj, args) =>
            {
                parentAppBar = parent.ApplicationBar;
                parent.ApplicationBar = this.ApplicationBar;
            };

        Unloaded += (obj, args) =>
            {
                parent.ApplicationBar = parentAppBar;
            };
    }

    private void menuItem3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        popup.IsOpen = false;
    }
```